# I don't want this "Open With Files" option to be there

Tags: nautilus, files, nautilus-actions

I have Nautilus-Actions but I don't know if this is the cause or not.
I don't use any Nautilus scripts except Folder-color which I installed today -- not sure but maybe is the cause.

[image: option for opening folder with Files]

[Also for Video Player I find 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnv4a.png)

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version and flavour?

Comment: Maybe you installed Nemo or another file manager that's also name "Files" in its .desktop file.

Comment: @pomsky 16.04 normal with gnome 3.18 (Nautilus too)

Comment: @wjandrea No I didn't , I tried to install the latest Gnome as a Snap but after doing so I didn't find it so I removed it.